# Displaying images in jsf

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish, javabeans

Im having a strange problem of displaying image in jsf. I have a images on server in folder:
**/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/images**.

I have full access to folder, can upload and delete images through bean and everything works fine but when I try to display images, nothing shows! I have tried the following:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/images/image.jpg"/> 
<h:graphicImage value="/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/images/image.jpg"/>
<img src="/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/images/image.jpg">
```

but nothing seems to work. 
Not sure what im doing wrong here so any help is welcome. Big thx in advance

Comment: You seem to expect that it's the webserver who somehow inlines images in the generated HTML output. This is completely wrong. It's the webbrowser who downloads images individually based on the URL found in the `src` attribute while parsing the retrieved HTML output. This has further nothing to do with JSF.

Comment: well, I couldn't figure out how the resource url was mapped through application

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like images is being hosted separately,

```
<h:graphicImage url="<urlpath>/images/image.jpg" width="200" height="171" />
```

e.g.

```
<h:graphicImage url="http://localhost:8080/images/image.jpg" width="200" height="171" />
```

Comment: Is it being hosted separately (can you use a url to access the image), because if its outside the context, you cannot access it by providing a path-location.

Comment: hm, i'll try that just sec

Comment: hm I can't use url, but I don't get it, I can access it through my bean but not through tag?

Comment: big thx man, your answer pointed me at right direction                I looked up root folder of my index web page and navigated from there to image folder

Answer (score 1):

The `src` attribute is the `URL` of the image that can be accessed on the Internet. It's not the path to the file on your machine. Take a look at this short [article](http://www.marceble.com/2009/07/virtual-directories-in-glassfish/) on how to set up Virtual directory. What you need to do after that is straight-forward :).